# Ionic AdMobPro plugin: adMob Banner shown on Android only

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new with ionic and I really don't understand why this code works on android only... Banners aren't shown on iOS.
It should be simple but doesn't work.

```
openBanner() {
    let adId;
    if(this.platform.is('android')) { adId = 'BANNERID'; }
    else if (this.platform.is('ios')) { adId = 'BANNERID'; }
    let bannerConfig: AdMobOptions = { isTesting: true, autoShow: true, adId: adId };
    this.admob.createBanner(bannerConfig);
  }
```

Thanks